# Syntax of function declaration in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I would like to define a function as following:

```
let f (a: int) (b: int) (c: int) (d: int): int =
  ...
```

Is it possible to make the signature shorter without making them a tuple? As I still want `f` to have 4 arguments.

Thank you very much.

**Edit1:** I just think it is useless to repeat `int` 4 times, and image something like `let f (a, b, c, d: int): int` which actually is not allowed at the moment.

Comment: You don't need to annotate all arguments with their types. It's generally not needed. You enforce types in the module interfaces, but otherwise the syntax is not optimized for it because it's not the expected programming style. Annotations are good for polymorphic variants, but otherwise you shouldn't have to use them so much.

Comment: I find gasche's "the syntax is not optimized for it because it's not the expected programming style" remark insightful. A small exception that does not contradict his general rule is that when the compiler rejects a long recursive definition, a small type annotation can very much help the compiler help you fix it with a relevant error message.

Comment: @gasche What do you mean exactly by "the syntax is not optimized"? How can a syntax be optimized or not optimized?

Comment: Designing a syntax requires making many compromises that make some things longer to express than some others. I would say that a syntax is "optimized" for a specific usage when it makes it as short as possible. For example, OCaml's syntax is "optimized" for curried functions and chaining of "if then else" expressions without an "elif" keyword, and on the contrary it is not very good as supporting the partial application of the second argument of an infix operators, or to locally declare exceptions.

Answer (score 13):

Try this syntax:

```
let g: int -> int -> int -> int -> int =
  fun a b c d -> 
     assert false
```

It's not much shorter, but if you have a lot of these,  you can define `type arith4 = int -> int -> int -> int -> int` and use that name as type annotation for `g`.

Answer (score 1):

My OCaml is rusty but I believe you can do that by declaring your own type and by unpacking it in the function body.

```
type four = int*int*int*int

let myfunction (t:four) = 
   let a, b, c, d = t in 
      a + b + c + d;
```

You can also do this:

```
let sum4 ((a, b, c, d):int*int*int*int) = 
   a + b + c + d;;
```

Comment: I interpret the "I still want f to have 4 arguments." in the function as meaning exactly that this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: I considered that but I felt this might be a reasonable alternative (with a compromise) for the asker and anyone else (who may have varying requirements) that might stumble upon this question.

Comment: If your point is to use a type alias to avoid repeating the same type for similar functions, you can also do that in curried style. `type 'a four = int -> int -> int -> int -> 'a;;`.